# kendo grid odd behaviour around service instantiation

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I'm using a Kendo Grid in an Angular template and trying to allow a service in the component to define some css styling but having a problem.

```
<kendo-grid
*ngIf="canLoad()"
[data]=etc...
[rowClass] = "rowCallback"
>

public canLoad() : boolean
{
  return this.myservice !== undefined;
}

public rowCallback(context: RowClassArgs)
{
  this.myservice.doSomething();
}
```

I get an error **"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'doSomething')"** ... why do I get an error when the ngIf check has evaluated myservice as being instantiated? How can I get the rowCallback to wait until the service has been instantiated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above example `this.myservice.doSomething()` `this` is not pointing to the component class object, so myservice is undefined.

To fix this you can either

1. Bind `this` to the method when assigning `rowClass`

```html
<kendo-grid
*ngIf="canLoad()"
[data]=etc...
[rowClass] = "rowCallback.bind(this)"
>
```

2. Use an arrow function to define `rowCallback`

```js
public rowCallback = (context: RowClassArgs) => {
  this.myservice.doSomething();
}
```